# Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am tryig to set up JPA to my RESTful webapi in order to make CRUD services on database. I am getting the error `Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath` But actually ther in a persistence.xml in the folder `META-INF`

```
1 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.5.6-Final
    17 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.6-Final
    20 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
    23 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
    27 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
    110 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
    115 [main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.6-Final
    129 [main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named KAPAPLAN
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
        at de.ham.ti.kapaplan.database.DBCon.main(DBCon.java:20)
```

here my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"

  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="KAPAPLAN" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>de.ham.ti.kapaplan.model</class>

    <properties>
      <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//***db-domain***/***service-name***" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***user***" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***pw***" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysema.query.jpa.support.ExtendedOracleDialect" />

      <!-- Hibernate properties -->
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

      <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
      <!-- <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />-->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I double checked similar questions but non of them solved my issue. ann ideas?

**EDIT:** my Maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.ham.ti.kapaplan</groupId>
    <artifactId>kapaplan</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kapaplan</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>kapaplan</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your project's structure. Is it a maven one?

Comment: i edited an added the pom structure

Comment: Why would you look for a provider "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" in a jar that doesn't provide it (hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6) ?

Comment: Is your META-INF/persistence.xml in your-project/src/main/resources? It should be enought.

Comment: WEB-INF is in src/main/resources sitll not working

Comment: WEB-INF should not stay there. It should stay in src/main/webapp folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your project is misconfigured. META-INF folder should stay in src/main/resources and WEB-INF folder in `src/main/webapp` of your web maven project. Here is an [example](https://github.com/fpezzati/Yomoka/tree/master/YoOffer) where I do some CRUD over web api.

Comment: Well i think you were right. I set up a new project and it worked fine. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to move persistence.xml to a location on your app server's class path. For a Maven project, that is typically in the `src/main/resources` folder. Check the Hibernate documentation to see if Hibernate expects the file to be in a sub-folder, or if putting it in the root of the classpath is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set the path for your META-INF in a maven project is to use the pom.xml and set the path directly over there by using the directory tag. I was facing the same problem but solved it using this.
ex:- your META-INF is present in the src folder
your pom.xml will be:

```xml
     <dependencies>
     ..
     </dependencies>
     <build>
       
       <resources>
         <resource>
           <directory>E:/Netbeans Repo/Hibernate/src</directory>
         </resource>
       </resources>

     </build>
```

This should work