# Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath Java - Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, xml, jpa

My problem s just same as this [Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593857/could-not-find-any-meta-inf-persistence-xml-file-in-the-classpath) and i need to help about how i just simply add my persistence.xml file into the in the classpath.

> App.java

```
package JPA;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Alien a = em.find(Alien.class,2);
    }
}
```

> persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"  >   
    <persistence-unit name="pu">   
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/akash"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Here i am little confused about the persistence" version="1.0" is correct or not ?**

**> Error**

> Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
>
> No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pu

[image]

my persistence.xml file is stored into the META-INF so why it shows error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It helps me**

> I created a new JPA Project from File-> New -> JPA Project.
>
> It provided me the correct **location of META-INF** Folder which is consists of
>
> `persistence.xml`
>
> Then i add the JPA Project Facets to my project and  provided all the necessary details related to my database connection.
>
> Simply run my App.java file .
>
> It runs.

**New Project Source**

[image]